# Tibco businessworks 6.6. JDBC Resource connection - Snowflake

Tags: jdbc, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, tibco-business-works

Has anyone successfully created a JDBC Resource connection for the Snowflake database? I have a specific case, where I would like to connect directly, not through Snowflake plugin. I am stuck at database driver selection. Can't import snowflake-jdbc-3.13.24.jar to choose it in dropdown menu.

I already tried this, but it doesn't work:
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.2.1/doc/html/GUID-DF12A927-F788-46DC-ABA1-0A1BA797DE2F.html

[image: I would like to get snowflake-jdbc-3.13.24.jar driver in this dropdown menu]

Comment: The class for Snowflake should be: **net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver** and the URL should look like: **jdbc:snowflake://<account>.snowflakecomputing.com:443/?user=${username}&password=${password}&db=${db}&schema=${schema}&role=${role}&warehouse=${warehouse}**

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but Database driver should be installed somehow, otherwise it's not shown at the drop-down menu "Database Driver" as presented in the picture above.

Installing through CMD (like JDBC driver for DB2) is not successful. Here is the output:

C:\TIBCO\bw660\bw\6.6\bin>bwinstall.exe net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver
Buildfile: C:\TIBCO\bw660\bw\6.6\scripts\bwinstall.xml

BUILD FAILED
Target "net.snowflake.client.jdbc.SnowflakeDriver" does not exist in the project "bwinstall".

Total time: 0 seconds

C:\TIBCO\bw660\bw\6.6\bin>

Answer (score 0):

I never worked with Snowflakes but the BusinessWorks 6.6 documentation provides updated explanations on how to set-up a custom JDBC driver in the BusinessWorks environment, you can check it at the following URL :
https://docs.tibco.com/pub/activematrix_businessworks/6.6.1/doc/html/GUID-DF12A927-F788-46DC-ABA1-0A1BA797DE2F.html